# How to select distinct data from two tables based on two parameters?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two lists.
StateNotes - State, CropYear, ..Other properties
Pricings - State, CropYear, ..Other properties

I want to select *State* and *CropYear* of every record in **Pricings** table which is NOT present in StateNotes.

Example :

**StateNotes**

```
{State - Washington, CropYear - 2021 },
{State - Alabama, CropYear - 2022 },
{State - Nevada, CropYear - 2022 }
```

**Pricings**

```
{State - Washington, CropYear - 2021 },
{State - Alabama, CropYear - 2022 },
{State - Nevada, CropYear - 2021 } *<- this would be selected because there is no combination of Nevada-2021 in StateNotes*
```

What I tried :

```
var stateNotes = repository.AsQueryable<StateNotes>().ToList();
var newStates = pricings.Select(x => new { x.State, x.CropYear }).Except(stateNotes.Select(x => new { x.State, x.CropYear })).ToList();
```

Comment: *What I tried* -- what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var newStates = pricings.Where(x => !stateNotes.Any(p => p.State == x.State && p.CropYear == x.CropYear)).ToList();
```

Whit that function you select the difference between pricings and stateNotes